# What should I use FileMode.Open or FileMode.Create for to make changes to a binary file

Tags: c#

I am writing a list of complex objects to binary using BinaryFormatter and FileStream. For the method that writes the file, should I use FileMode.Create to make a new file and overwrite it with a completely new file or should I do something different that will open it and change only what has changed?

I am trying to serialize,deserialize,read,write the following:

```
List<Class> objectlist = new List<Class>();
```

Comment: Move original file to a backup and write a new file.

Comment: I am using this list as my main database so it is constantly being read and rewritten.

Comment: There's not really a good way to just modify part of the file.

Comment: Yes, it's inefficient to write a whole new file if all you want to do is modify part of it.

Comment: Usually one caches this in memory and reads/writes it to a file as needed, but for reliability etc. you eventually end up with an ACID compliant database engine.

Comment: So what is the best thing to do?

Comment: The most reliable thing is to do what @spender has stated. However, if you are serializing 2,000,000 of your Class, and you know that the positions of the Classes in the List haven't changed, and you really care about the speed of the serialization, you can write something complicated to modify the file (but if you're doing that, you should probably be using a database).

Comment: I agree with Kyle, for reliability you would want an ACID compliant database engine, like SQL Server, MySQL, etc.

Comment: If you can tolerate losing it (e.g. it can be rebuilt easily) then keep it in memory and write it out when idle or exiting.  If you can't tolerate losing it, you should use a reliable DB engine.  Or SQL lite.

Comment: It depends if you are just changing bytes or changing size as well.  Sometimes it is better to use c++.  Some binary files are setup like a file structure with pointers like a zip file.  When a zip file is modified most utilities don't deserialize the entire zip and then rebuild.  They modify they structure removing items by removing the pointers to the data leaving the unused bytes in the file.

Answer (score -1):

These two features should solve your problem. First create your file and other is read it.

```
public void WriteToBinaryFormatterFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite, bool append = false)
{
    using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, append ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.Create))
    {
        var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, objectToWrite);
    }
 }
```

To read your binary formatter file.

```
public T ReadFromBinaryFormatterFile<T>(string filePath)
{
    using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        return (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that appending to an existing serialized file like that works?  Even if it does, your `ReadFromBinaryFormatterFile` method would only read the *first* object in the stream, wouldn't it?